# AWS Cloudformation issue installing custom binaries

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudformation, templates

I'm trying to install a custom compiled package that I have in S3 as a zip file. I added this on my Cloudformation template:

```
"sources" : {
    "/opt" : "https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket/installers/myapp-3.2.1.zip"
},
```

It downloads and unzip it on /opt without issues, but all the "executables" files don't have the "x" permission. I mean "-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 220378 Dec 4 18:23 myapp".

If I download the zip and unzip it in any directory, the permissions are Ok.

I already read the Cloudformation documentation and there is no clue there.

Someone can help me figuring this out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I solved it adding a "files" section with "source" pointing to S3 and a "commands" section with the unzip command. I'm not sure if this is the best approach, but it is working.

Comment: I packaged the files into a tgz file and it worked as it should.

Comment: Sounds like the Cloudformation unzip implementation doesn't use tacky permissions flags, while the tar/untar  implementation does.

Comment: did you solve the problem?

Comment: yes, by using tarball instead of a zip file